# About using Convolutional layer's output as LSTM's input

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a question about how to combine convolutional layer and LSTM layer working together in Keras.

Suppose I am using a CNN to exact feature maps for an image. And after a particular convolutional layer, I have a feature map, say F, whose dimension is (H, W, C). Now, I want to use each row of this feature map, like [1::], [2::], ....., as the input of following LSTM layer, but iterate H times.

The output of LSTM is a (H, W) tensor.

Is there a way to do this in keras with the default layer? Or I need to implement a custom layer?

Thanks

---

I tried to use Timedistributed layer in my model but it doesn't work. Actually, what I want to implement is a simplified version of [link](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Byeon_Scene_Labeling_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf).

Here, I just want to use LSTM to scan each row of my Conv2D's outputs and label each pixel of it. My code is like following:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(256,256,1))

# encoder
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5))(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  # 128x128
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3))(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  # 64x64

# decoder
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3))(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5))(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

# Using LSTM to produce final outputs
decoded = TimeDistributed(LSTM(3, input_shape=(32, 16),return_sequences=True))(x)

model = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

But it looks like my model cannot converge......

Comment: see the example below the title "Visual question answering model" here: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ , it might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a general matrix manipulation. You just need to split the matrix into H matrices at the first dimension of the feature map and then feed each of them to your LSTM layer iteratively. You will get H 1*W vectors as the output of LSTM, concatenate them at the first dimension then you will get a H*W output.

Comment: Yes, it is a matrix manipulation indeed. But I am not sure if I implement this in Keras, do I need to create a layer to do this?

Comment: @simbabuffalo I'm not using keras but I think it's a general question. I don't see why you need another layer to do so since it doesn't need any transformation in your case.